# How to add android and iphone app for cordova in windows

Tags: cordova

How to add android and iphone app for cordova in windows.

When i add through this command : `cordova platform add android`

I am getting this below error

```
Creating android project...
C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 126
throw e; ^ Error: An error occurred
while listing Android targets
at C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js: 87: 29
at _rejected(C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 808: 24)
at C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 834: 30
at Promise.when(C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 1079: 31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch(C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 752: 41)
at C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 574: 44
at flush(C: \Users\dheeraj\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js: 108: 17)
at process._tickCallback(node.js: 415: 13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone(C: \Users\dheeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js: 112: 23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit(events.js: 98: 17)
at maybeClose(child_process.js: 735: 16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(child_process.js: 802: 5)
```

Please help to resolve this issue.
Thank in advance

Comment: Do you have the developer SDK's for Android and Iphone on your windows machine?

Comment: Hi Drew , I dont have developer SDK for both . What should i do ? . Please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Install ant using brew.

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am using windows OS . Please give idea according to that.